# Return type annotation for Tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have function:

```py
def func() -> tuple(str, list(str)):
    var_a = "four"
    var_b = ["one","two","three"]
    return var_a, var_b
```

And when I call it, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I have also tried it this way:

```py
from typing import Tuple
def func() -> Tuple[str, list(str)]:
    var_a = "four"
    var_b = ["one","two","three"]
    return var_a, var_b
```

And, I am met with the exact same error.

How to have the proper return type annotation for this case?

Comment: You need to use `typing` types for tuple *and* list, `list(str)` is the [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [`List[str]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List), the generic version of `list`:

```py
from typing import List, Tuple

def func() -> Tuple[str, List[str]]:
    var_a = "four"
    var_b = ["one","two","three"]
    return var_a, var_b
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parentheses, try using square brackets ([ and ]):

```py
def func() -> tuple[str, list[str]]:
    var_a = "four"
    var_b = ["one", "two", "three"]
    return var_a, var_b
```